# Images are not displayed in wordpress media Library

Tags: wordpress

Actually I am facing an error while uploading the images and insert it into post in wordpress.
Here I am Unable to view the uploaded images in the Media Library

[image: I am unable to upload and view the image]

Comment: is wp installation on your local server or on remote server ? are you using any ftp client ?

Comment: It might happen if you have turned on WP_DEBUG,and error display true, because the loader works on ajax, notices and warning makes it not work. And its quite possible that when you are using a particular theme, it is having warnings while other don't

Comment: Sir I am using Xampp server sir

Comment: No I checked in the wp-config file, I haven't done any changes in WP_DEBUG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check permission of that "upload" folder, give 777 or remove read only from whole subfolders of "upload" folder.

give 777 to "upload"

Thanks

Comment: Sir I don't how set permission please say detailed

Comment: go to the "wp-content" directory, and found "uploads" folder, right click over that, remove "read only" from bottom. and dont forget to apply same this to all subfolder of this folder.

Comment: Only If I am using my Theme this error is thrown and not when I use all other themes

Comment: check Settings → Media and make sure that Uploading Files folder is set to wp-content/uploads", please here dont put trailing slash after uploads

Comment: You can also use this plugin if it is not fixed yet: wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hotfix I hope it will work for you

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40629/discussion-between-hemanth-kumar-and-krunal-shah)

Answer (score 0):

Even after changing the permission to 777 i couldn't get it working in my latest wordpress 3.9.1 fresh install. Then i found out that my custom theme was out dated and i had to add the below line in functions.php file inside my custom theme folder

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-dialog', false, array('jquery'), false, true );
```

I found that from this link --> http://wordpress.org/support/topic/add-media-functionality-on-391-not-workingg

Hope that helps.